# Customize My Sites on SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, my-site

For a project I am working on, our group is hoping to heavily customize the SharePoint 2010 My Sites layout and design.

I've done some research and found the following link that explains how Feature Stapling is the suggested way of customizing the look/feel of these pages.

[Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/spsocial/customizing-my-sites-in-microsoft-sharepoint-2010)

Unfortunately, it only describes how to replace the Navigation delegate control. We'd like to modify and/or completely remove the profile badge area and replace it with a custom web-part that we develop (see screenshot below).

Anybody know how this can be done via Feature Stapling?

Any info and/or suggestions would be much appreciated.

[image: Profile Badge in SharePoint 2010]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two sides to the Personalized Sites; the "My Site" is a site collection owned by the user, and the other features like the Profile Page (Person.aspx) which is in a shared site collection used by all users in the User Profile Store.

Since the Person.aspx page is shared, it is a bit easier to customize those after deployment.  Feature stapling would be a bit overkill since it is only executed once.  Here is an article I wrote for customizing the page in SharePoint Designer:  http://nextconnect.blogspot.com/2010/09/disabling-whats-happening-display-on.html

Comment: Thanks, Mike. Great post!

I see one big downside to this approach, though. That markup is duplicated on multiple pages, including: Person.aspx, OrganizationView.aspx, PersonContent.aspx, and even some LAYOUT pages. So I would have to manually update all of these pages to get a new design deployed. Do you have any thoughts about this?

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you are looking to customize, and you provide some details?

Comment: In your blog post, you talk about hiding the status message by removing the control from Person.aspx. This works. HOWEVER, if you click on "Organization" or any other tabs within the My Site area, the status message will come back. This is because it is repeated on all the different pages (e.g. Person.aspx, OrganizationView.aspx, etc..). So you have to modify each of these pages individually. Unfortunately, I think it's the only way to go.

Comment: That is correct, each one is an individual page.  Sorry it wasn't clear.

Comment: If I want to customize some of the fields in the organization view, how do I do that? For example, the organization chart displays "about me" but I want to remove it from the organization browser. Many thanks

Comment: @Shridhar The organization viewer is not customizable like that, you would need to create your own and replace the existing one.