# Unable to customize My Sites in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, my-site

When I try to modify any page in the My Sites host using SharePoint designer 2010, I am able to change everything (remove webparts etc) *except* whatever is above the Quick launch nav items, the same region that is red-boxed item in [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6075/customize-my-sites-on-sharepoint-2010), i.e. the user details box.

I have a feeling it will be some silly permission thing--but the file is checked out to me, I've logged on to the one-server-wonder as the site collection admin/central admin app pool account, i.e. GOD user, and I am still unable to modify anything in the person box.

I've just watched a [web cast](http://www.bing.com/videos/watch/video/customizing-my-sites-and-social-features-in-sharepoint-2010/10t7md1g2) of the exact same thing done so I know it IS possible. Can you please help with an idea on what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is an 'Advanced Edit' button or something in SPD2010 that otherwise restricts access to some bits of the HTML.... that worked.